# Magento multi websites not working properly when point to new add on domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, magento-1.7

i followed this tutorial
http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-set-multiple-websites-with-multiple-store-views-in-magento/
and works fine like this
yourwebsite[at]com/website2 but when i point yourwebsite[dot]com/website2 to domain2[dot]com it does not work properly and when i click on any category it takes me to http://yourwebsite.com/website2/clickedcategory but i want domain2[dot]com/clickedcategory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the URL setup in Magento.

```
Configuration -> web -> frontend URL
```

change this to newdomain.com/ (you will need to select the store from the store selection dropdown too).

then refesh all Magento cache and indexes, and the links should now point to the correct URL.

Comment: i changed base link url to newdomain.com/ and home page loads perfect but when i click on category it gives me error The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: can you enable display_errors and developer mode inside index.php and then see what error message you get

Comment: Andrew thanx for reply just tell me that above mentioned tutorial will work on Magenento 1.7 ?

Comment: yeah that should be fine, once you get that error message you will know more about whats going on..it could be an htaccess issue etc

Comment: This is main installation http://yellowsapphire.org.in/sp/ and other website is http://yellowsapphire.org.in/sp/magento2 which is pointed to 9gem.in please check if you can get anything .

Comment: you will need to check your aache error log, it's not a Magento specific issue :)

Comment: have you also setup the domains correctly in apache? that would also need done. Apache needs to actually be listening for those domains, usually you would "park" them

Comment: Error log says  PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: mageRunType in /home/yellowsa/public_html/sp/magento2/index.php on line 89

Comment: it's not the issue causing the 500 error, although you should also take care of that :)